# Multiple Values in Xpath Filter String

Tags: xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I am applying a metadata filter to an existing XML document that looks like this:

```
//description[text()='Desc'] and //keyword[@ddms:value='Adv1']
```

My question is, how would I filter multiple keywords? Would it be as simple as:

```
//description[text()='Desc'] and //keyword[@ddms:value='Adv1', 'Adv2', 'Adv3', 'etc']
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what version of XPath.

XPath 2.0 can handle sequences:

```xml
//keyword[@ddms:value=('Adv1', 'Adv2', 'Adv3', 'etc')]
```

XPath 1.0 is more verbose:

```xml
//keyword[@ddms:value='Adv1' or @ddms:value='Adv2' or @ddms:value='Adv3']
```